# How can I search less than needed date with springdata and mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, spring-data-rest

Try to search by date from mongodb via springdata generated method. But I can't. What do I wrong?

I tried

```
@RestResource(path = "findByEndDate")
List<Event> findByEndDate(@Param("endDate") Date java.util.Date.endDate);
```

OR

```
@RestResource(path = "findByEndDate")
List<Event> findByEndDate(@DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ")@Param("endDate") Date endDate);
```

but unsuccessfully

Data stored in database:

```
        {
          "_embedded" : {
            "events" : [ {
              "uuid" : "TEST_UUID_EVENT",
              "testObject" : true,
              "startDate" : "2016-07-29T11:23:41.815+0000",
              "endDate" : "2016-07-29T23:23:41.815+0000"
              ...
```

Comment: Whether you are getting any error or not finding the document?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

By looking your schema the data `endDate` is present inside events[], so it should be queried like as follows

```
@RestResource(path = "findByEndDate")
List<Event> findByEndDate(@Param("events.endDate") Date java.util.Date.endDate);
```

This document lists on various ways of querying the mongodb thru spring data.

http://www.mkyong.com/mongodb/spring-data-mongodb-query-document/